# How to convert from timestamp to date in Qt?

Tags: qt, datetime, timestamp

I have a Unix timestamp and I need to convert it to human readable date + time. How can it be done in Qt?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
int unixTime = 1234567890;
QDateTime timestamp;
timestamp.setTime_t(unixTime);
qDebug() << timestamp.toString(Qt::SystemLocaleShortDate);
```

That should get you going. Like Matthew said, see [QDateTime.setTime_t](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#setTime_t), as well as [QDateTime.toString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toString). The toString has an enumeration with several different options, as well as an overload where you can pass a string allowing however much customization you like.

Answer (score 7):

[`QDateTime.setTime_t`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qdatetime.html#setTime_t)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the static function: "fromTime_t", like:

qDebug() << QDateTime::fromTime_t(your_time_stamp).toString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

Answer (score 4):

One good example

```
qint64 qiTimestamp=QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
QDateTime dt;
dt.setTime_t(qiTimestamp/1000);
ui->lineEdit_DateTime->setText(dt.toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that `QDateTime::setTime_t()` has been deprecated, use `QDateTime::setSecsSinceEpoch()`. Same for `fromTime_t()`: use QDateTime::fromSecsSinceEpoch().

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, instead of using the obsolete `_t` members here is a working example (Qt 5).

```
qint64 llTS=1591132400;
QString szFull=QDateTime::fromSecsSinceEpoch(llTS).toString("dddd d MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

**szFull**: **Tuesday 2 June 2020 23:13:20**

Source: [QDateTime (Qt 5)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html)

Date formatting: [QDate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#fromString)

Time formatting: [QTime](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#toString)